# Effects in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, when we have more than one effect, such that the effect has to go simultaneously or
first complete the first effect and then proceed to next one, how do we do that?

If I use 2 effects, the first effect is not seen and the second one is seen.

Here is what I'm trying to do.  I'm using a roundabout function move over the images, and when you click on any one of the images I am scrolling the page using the `scrollTo()` method.

The problem is that the roundabout function is not seen.  Only the scrolling effect is seen.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow without an example but if you're looking to have one effect start only after another has completed, you should put the second effect in a function inside the callback of the first effect.

Comment: i added a call back function but the second function is not getting executed.I don't exactly kno whether it will work or not because it is aplugin what i'm using.i don't know whether u can write call back function in plugin??

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I am not sure if this is what you want.. So Try and let me know how it goes.

```
$(function(){ 
        $('ul').roundabout(function() { 
            $('img').click(function(){ 
                $('#outermost').scrollTo($(this).attr('id'),800); 
                return false; 
            }); 
        });
});
```

You can queue using . and call the function after completing the first effect. Something like below,

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000)
      .show("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/HESCq/)** here

Comment: Hmmm, isn't that called chaining?

Comment: @ j08691 - It can be, yes, but what it actually does is add them to the queue one after the other.

Comment: $(function(){

 $('ul').roundabout();

 $('img').click(function(){

  

  $('#outermost').scrollTo($(this).attr('id'),800);  

  return false;
}); This is the jquery code  help me in combining these two function so the scrollTo() is executed after roundabout() function

Comment: See my Edits. I never used roundAbout plugin and I am still not sure if that is what you want. Try and let me know.

Comment: i tried this but only the roundabout function is executed and not the scrollTo()

Comment: Can you set this up in jsFiddle.net, so I can take a look?